# How to Pass Field Value to Another Field in Google Forms

Tags: google-apps-script, google-forms

I am trying to create a form in Google-forms with below requirement

Field1: Full Name _____

Field2: Declaration: I [Full name entered above] declare that above given information is correct.

Here I want to copy whatever name entered in Field1 (Full Name) to Field 2 dynamically when response is getting filled up.
Is there any way I can achieve this through google-app-scripts ?

Comment: Do you wish to do this in the spreadsheet where the answers are stored?

Comment: If you are asking if google apps script can write the response of question one into the answer for question two while the form is being filled in before it is submitted then the answer is no.  There is no programmatic access to Google Form via apps script like there is via webapps or dialogs